# Navigation Bar Title background is white in iOS11

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

For some reason in iOS 11 the title label in navigation bar has a white background:

[image: navigation bar with white background for title]

This is just a normal navigation controller and the title is being set the default way:

```
self.title = @"My Title";
```

This problem is only happening in iOS 11 and the screenshot was taken from the simulator, otherwise for previous iOS version this works fine.

Any suggestions as to how i can have a normal clear background label or remove the white background which is coming up for whatever reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have set the title text attributes correctly. You can set the title text attributes from the Storyboard or Programatically. Select `Storyboard -> NavigationBar -> Go to attribute inspector -> Title Text Attributes`

[image]

or in ViewController try setting it manually

**Swift 4:**

```
         self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
            NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .bold)
        ]
```

**Swift 3:**

```
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .bold)
        ]
```

Comment: This wasn't exactly a fix in my case, but it did help me to search and find out the problem so I am accepting this answer. I was modifying code which was written by someone else also and a UINavigationBar category was being used which had the code to set those titleTextAttributes except it set both foreground and background both to white, so i set the background to be clear and it's working fine now, thanks for the help

Comment: great, it's a good idea to keep it in UINavigationController or NavigationBar extension. I think you don't need to set the backgroundColor attribute as its defaults to nil. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey/1528791-backgroundcolor